# Invariant Violation Error when using drawer in React native

Tags: react-native, drawer, hamburger-menu

[image]

> **ERROR**  TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating
> '_ReanimatedModule.default.createNode')
> **ERROR**  Invariant Violation:
> Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling
> runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application
> entry file path is incorrect.
> This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
> **ERROR**
> Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable
> module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that
> the application entry file path is incorrect.
> This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.

When I using Drawer sample code, I got this error.

```
  function NotificationsScreen({ navigation }) {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
        <Button 
        onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
        title="Go back home"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
export default function App() {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
        <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
          <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
          <Drawer.Screen name="Notifications" component={NotificationsScreen} />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
```

I googled and found some answers of stackoverflow, but it didn't help.
I added this to babel.config.js, but it doesn't work.

```
 plugins: [
    "react-native-reanimated/plugin",
  ],
```

Comment: Please share your ```HomeScreen``` code.